# How to import a NET .dll newer than 2.0 into Unity?

Tags: unity, visual-studio, .net, dll

I'm trying to build one of the simple `EventBus` libraries from Github and import them into Unity. Here are the libs:

[TinyMessenger](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger) and
[RedBus](https://github.com/mxjones/RedBus)

It's that simple - I take the source code, build it through the VS2015 and place the `.dll` into the `Assets/Plugins` folder.

Then, I have no way to use the lib's namespace (Unity doesn't read the file).

Both of these libraries are written in NET 3 or 4 and this is the failure's reason.
I've recompiled the second one (removed the `System.Linq` code, changed the project's version) to `NET 2.0` and it worked, but that's not the point. I need the first library and it isn't easy to rewrite the entire 4.0 code to 2.0 without Linq.

As I remember, you can use `System.Linq` in Unity (at least, I did it once). This means that Unity uses some kind of trickery/magic, as always.

What's the problem here? Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: It should be possible instruct VS compiler to output for older versions of .NET. How to do that exactly I am not sure, but can give you a lead - the [C# 6 project](https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/src) which did that for Unity projects. Adapting the solution for generic libraries should be possible as well.

Comment: Yes, it is possible through project settings. But the project is coded for a `NET > 2` it uses Linq everywhere.

Comment: Well... it is *exactly* what the linked project does - allow you using the C# 6 features throughout the project and then compile it into .NET 2.0 compatible CLR The problem I see is if the said libraries depend on *other* libraries that could not be loaded. "Microsoft and Mono compilers can compile C# 5/6/7 code for CLR 2.0 if you explicitly ask them to do so." explicitly stated in second sentence of the projects description.